# I am downloading Eclipse. But what else do I need to develop Java EE applications?

Tags: eclipse

I am downloading [this version of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2). I want to know what else I should download and install before I can start working on Java EE applications.

Previously I used to work with NetBeans. Back then, I used to install these:

1. JRE
2. JDK
3. NetBeans
4. Tomcat

Then I could develop Java EE applications.

Is the same set of steps required when I download that Eclipse too? Or do some of the things come bundled with it? Please help me out with setting up the development environment.

Comment: If you intend to develop with Java EE 6 / JSF 2.0, you may find [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) useful. It describes the steps from the zero beginning on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't bundle JRE/JDK or app servers. Make sure you download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package (as others will not have the plugins you need). You will need to download JDK and Tomcat separately. Note that there is no need to also download a JRE as JDK install has a JRE in it.

Note that Eclipse does have en embedded Jetty server that can be used for previewing your app without a separate app server, but most non-trivial apps still require downloading and installing the specific app server you intend to deploy in production on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official website:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html

I had installed my enviroment from these website and work properly, the server is up and running.

Tomcat is a software implementation, you need to install it separately. Take a look at the official tomcat's website at: http://tomcat.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a web site, my suggestions would be:

JRE/JDK, Apache Tomcat Application Server, Freemarker templating language (for page-building), Apache Web Server (for proxying, rewriting, mod_jk to load balance tomcat worker(s)), Varnish or Squid Cache, MySQL (to host UGC data (user generated content), and some kind of open source CMS system (Drupal or others) to host data that's web site editor created.